# I need to hide QTableWidget by default

Tags: c++, python, qt, qt4, pyqt

I need to hide the entire `QTableWidget` and show it. I  didn't find the same `function` for both in its documentation. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTableWidget` is a `QWidget`. Just use the `hide()` function.

Comment: wow, found, `self.tableWidget.setVisible(False)`

Comment: `hide()` is a slot that is equivalent to `setVisible(false)`